# IOS App Rejection ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - applicationWillTerminate cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Im building an application hybrid application using cordova using the following plugins

```
    "com.lampa.startapp": "0.1.4",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-calendar": "4.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "2.2.1",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "2.2.5",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-calendar": {},
      "com.lampa.startapp": {},
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
```

the application got rejected from apple with the following error message.

> Dear Developer, We identified one or more issues with a recent
>   delivery for your app, "AppName" . Please correct the following
>   issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
>   selectors in Idealys: applicationWillTerminate, ddSetLogLevel:,
>   localTarget, newSocketQueueForConnectionFromAddress:onSocket:,
>   setOrientation:animated:, socket:didConnectToHost:port:,
>   socket:didReadPartialDataOfLength:tag:,
>   socket:didReceiveTrust:completionHandler:,
>   socket:didWritePartialDataOfLength:tag:,
>   socket:shouldTimeoutReadWithTag:elapsed:bytesDone:,
>   socket:shouldTimeoutWriteWithTag:elapsed:bytesDone:,
>   socketDidCloseReadStream:, socketDidSecure:, terminateWithSuccess,
>   webSocket:didReceiveMessage:, webSocketDidOpen:. If method names in
>   your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering
>   your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in
>   future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above
>   APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your
>   app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the
>   Technical Support Information at
>   http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/  Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I think the rejection is caused by a cordova pluggin but i have had a hard time troubleshooting the error.

Comment: What if you try to search some of those calls (like `applicationWillTerminate ` / `newSocketQueueForConnectionFromAddress` / etc.) in your project folder, do you  find anything? The  `grep` command might do the trick! For example `grep -lr "newSocketQueueForConnectionFromAddress" *`

Comment: I've tried to look for `applicationWillTerminate` on the xcode workspace and i've found it on CDVPlugin but it seems to be just a warning saying it use UIApplicationWillTerminate instead. and for the other calls like `newSocketQueueForConnectionFromAddress` i didnt found anything.

I'll try with the grep command