# ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage PROCESSING ERROR - Previously Working

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ios16

Upon uploading a binary to `App Store Connect`, I receive this email from Apple:

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public selectors in [PROJECT NAME HERE]: callWithArguments:, estimatedProgress, frameInfo, getVersion, initWithFrame:configuration:, isMainFrame, navigationDelegate, navigationType, setNavigationDelegate:, setProcessPool:, targetFrame, toDouble, toString, userContentController. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

However, other than the build number increasing from `1.2` to `1.2.1`, this is the exact same Binary that has been previously uploaded (and is live).

I've checked other questions on StackOverflow, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68197475/itms-90338-non-public-api-usage-adbannerview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085633/ios-app-rejection-itms-90338-non-public-api-usage-applicationwillterminate-co?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C271.4252), however are typically in reference to third party SDKs.

I am completely baffled as I don't use these method names at all, anywhere in the project...

Is this an issue with iOS 16 having been just released?
Thank you.

Comment: @matt It's not an App Store Rejection. It's a Binary that's not being processed because of Xcode. I simply don't use those methods...?

Comment: I am seeing this as well

Comment: I also have this issue, and many others are commenting on this old iOS thread all of a sudden starting within the last 2 hours https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127678?login=true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**
This issue has been resolved on the app validation backend. Resubmitting should work.
[source](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127678?answerId=715975022#715975022)

---

**Original Answer**

I'm also experiencing this issue this morning. A simple search of my project reveals many usages of these WKWebView APIs that are clearly public.

I suspect the issue is due to an issue with App Store builds linking against the freshly announced iOS16/Mac updates this morning. Unless those APIs have been outright banned today with no warning (unlikely), I'd put money on it being an Apple issue which they will resolve ASAP.

Comment: Thank you. I saw users on `Github` confirming the fix from Apple devs, and I was just about to post it here, but you beat me to it. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways online but finally found one way out. Refer to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31507#issuecomment-1043292372) comment on the gihub issue. Hope you find this helpful!